# How can I make an array of the names of images in a sibling directory in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, directory

Currently, I have something like this

```js
function iconPic(x){
    switch(x) {
        case 3: return "Icon2.svg";
        case 2: return "Icon1.svg";
        case 1: return "Icon.svg";
        default: return "Icon.png";
    }
}
```

Instead I want to have something like this

```js
var icons = array_of_icon_names_in_the_icons_directory;
```

So icons[0] would output "Icon.png" and icons[1] would output "Icon.svg" and so on

I found somewhere that this can be done with require('fs') somehow, but doing that won't work in web browsers. I need it to work in web browsers.

The files are like this:

```
index.html
thisProgram.js
icons
    Icon2.svg
    Icon1.svg
    Icon.svg
    Icon.png
```

Comment: Javascript will not read the filesystem as you are hoping. Imagine if your webpage were able to list the files on each and every user that visited your site? Or do you refer to files on the server? NodeJs might be an option if that is the case or other server side language - php, asp etc